# Event listener vs event handler

Tags: javascript, events

Can someone explain what is the proper way to make certain actions call functions in javascript? Should I use event handlers like `onclick="callFunction();"`? Or should I use an  event listener? If yes, how do they work?

Comment: looks like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215379/javascript-event-listeners-vs-event-handlers

Comment: Read this: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html Then read this: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

Comment: @Scott I read that question before posting this. I still didn't get it.